# How can I simplify this task screen for mobiles

Tags: gui-design, mobile, design-patterns

The Dropdown option are: All, Monthly, Weekly, Daily

The second row shows the current date range. If you select weekly, it would show "7. Sep-13. Sep". You can swipe left or right to change the date ranges or click the arrows.

[image]

Comment: What is the real UX question here? Phrased like this your question seems more like a site review, and not a question that has answers which could help others as well.

Comment: Is this on Android or iOS?

Comment: It's on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the time period selection by using a segmented (tab) control rather than a drop down.

This gives you one-tap access to change, vs. tap -> scroll -> tap

If I were to do a quick napkin sketch, I'm thinking something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0WNjH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Now, the above is based on the assumption that a user may need to quickly switch between all, month, week, day. If they don't actually need to flip through those, then I think your drop down idea is OK. But I may treat it as a FILTER option in the upper right of the menu bar instead.

Comment: That means I'll have 3 bars at the top. Navigation Bar, Tabs with "Monthly", "Weekly" etc. and another bar for showing the date ranges. That's too many bars at the top.

Comment: @Thegreatdev I added a visual for you.